# Autolayot aspect ratio iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, aspect-ratio, ios-autolayout

I can not set perfect Autolayout for Login and Facebook login button below forgot password. They are disappear from screen after setting Autolayout. Here I have attached my project link.

I want to expand all object proportionally same as like we get by using AutoResizeing

I have suffering problem to expand some objects with aspect ratio. its just two simple view for login

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5mabdphYDhzdllJYzY0czVrbFk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @BhadreshKathiriya or any one can help me

Comment: i can do it, i have downloaded the files. Posting the updated source in a GitHub repository soon.

Comment: i am facing a problem. i haven't installed xcode 8 and your storyboard is in xcode 8 saved. Sorry bro.

Comment: Thanks For response i will upload using Xcode 7 Wait a minutes

Comment: @M.K. I have uploaded new project which was made in Xcode 7 you can run it 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5mabdphYDhzdllJYzY0czVrbFk/view?usp=sharing

Thanks Bro for help

Comment: ok, i try this code... wait...

Comment: why you are use 2 imageview? Please share your need screen shot.

Comment: @BhadreshKathiriya becuase there 1 Image for Background and give I have to set Opacity also but not in Image

Comment: you are share screen shot? I understand original view.

Comment: @BhadreshKathiriya ok wait a miniute

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123244/discussion-between-bhadresh-kathiriya-and-ankur-patel).

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5mabdphYDhzUlhPSnlfT3l2LTg/view?usp=sharing

XCODE GET HANG SORRY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Constraint this type:

First Screen:
[image]

Second Screen:
[image]

your storyboard file:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_HNPywgMhtVTkJqQzd0QWlnZVU

Answer (score 1):

I have added auto layout constraints to your story board. Check the code in below link. Its a public repo and will be available forever.

https://github.com/mahesh-agrawal/Autolayout-Problem

tell me if any problem.

Comment: how did you set Proportional Width of Objects 
and There is more space between Forgot Password and Login as compared to 320*568 View Design

Comment: to set proportional width you need to add equal width constraint and then change multiplier like i did. and for spacing if you want the spacings dynamic then we need to use spacing views in between those elements which will have proportional height to top most view. So the gaps will be also dynamic.